# Translation with google trad api

Tags: api, file, pdf, translation

I'm trying to write a program that takes the text of a file, for example PDF, and translates the text extracted with the Google API, except that the API doesn't work with my code. I don't have a clue why it isn't working.

I've already tried to modify my code but nothing I've done works.

```py
from tika import parser
# from googletrans import Translator
import os
from textblob import TextBlob

#os.remove("arifureta.txt")
#os.remove("arifureta-formater.txt")
#os.remove("arifureta-traduit.txt")


raw = parser.from_file('/home/tom/Téléchargements/Arifureta_ From Commonplace to World_s Strongest Vol. 1.pdf')
text = raw['content']
text = text.replace('https://mp4directs.com','')
text = text.replace('\t','')
text = text.replace('\r','')
fichier = open("arifureta.txt", "a")
fichier.write(text)
fichier.close()

fic = open("arifureta-formater.txt", "a")
cpt=0
with open("arifureta.txt") as f :
    for line in f :
        if len(line)==1 :
            cpt+=1
        else :
            cpt=0
        if cpt<2:
            fic.write(line)
fic.close()

nbLigneTraité = 0
fic2 = open("arifureta-traduit.txt", "a")
compteur=0
textPasTraduit=''
with open("arifureta-formater.txt") as f :
    for line in f :
        fic2.write(str(blob.translate(from_lang='en',to='fr')))
        if len(line)>1:
            textPasTraduit += line
            compteur+=1
        if compteur%1000==0:
            blob = TextBlob(textPasTraduit)
            try:
                fic2.write(str(blob.translate(from_lang='en',to='fr')))
                print(blob.translate(from_lang='en',to='fr'))
            except Exception as e:
                pass
            nbLigneTraité+=1
            print(nbLigneTraité)
        if len(line)==1:
            fic2.write('\n')

fic2.close()
```

I expect to have the entire translation of the PDF's text in the result file, but actually the answer is 'broken link'. I think it is due to the quantity of text, but I haven't find a way to try any other method.

Comment: Please help 

Comment: I'm desesperate